# Disabled Android Button Dimmed

Tags: android, button

I am creating my first Android App that will be making profit, selling it to a company. I am not very advanced yet in Android App Development.

I have two buttons. I have been able to detect when the bottom of a ScrollView has been reached. Once that happens, one of the buttons becomes clickable, Button.setClickable(true);

When the button is not clickable, I would like it dimmed.

Here is an example from another application I wrote of what I mean. It is written in Java, but it is not an Android App.

[image: JSpeak]

Many buttons and other components there are disabled until the one with the diamond (turns on scanning) is toggled on. Those disabled components have a dim look to them. I would like to know how to accomplish the same for Android. I have searched Google but not found anything relevant yet.

P.S. If you would like to know more about the software in that picture I created. It is open source and you can check it out here.

https://github.com/BullShark/JSpeak

Comment: UPDATE: The closest answer I could find is getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);     But it is not letting me use those methods on a Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried

`myButton.setEnabled(false);`?

or

`android:clickable` can be used via xml

Comment: Button.setEnabled(false) was exactly what I was looking for. For some reason, when tried hit control + space in Eclipse for all the .set methods, it wasn't showing the first time, but I was looking for it. I had just gone under the assumption that it wasn't available for Android Java. This solution works exactly the way I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Similar answer to Anup Cowkur, but I believe it's cleaner and a better practice to define a single `drawable` with different states.

**dimmable_button.xml** (put in your res/drawables folder)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item state_enabled="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/clickable_image" />
     <item state_enabled="false"
           android:drawable="@drawable/dimmed_image" />
</selector>
```

Then, the `layout` file where your button is defined:

```
<button
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/dimmable_button" />
```

Now, when you do `button.setEnabled(bool)` the button's background will change automatically to a dimmed one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make another image with whatever look you want and change the background of the image to it when it is not clickable.

When it is dimmed out:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dim_image);
```

When it becomes clickable again:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clickable_image);
```